# Iphone SDK Sending Data using Carrier Data Network?

Tags: iphone

Could someone suggest a tutorial/sample on how an Iphone application can send data to a remote server using Carrier Data Network only? In other words is there a way an application can programmatically force to enable Carrier Data Network communication, use it to send its request to the remote server and switch it back to user specific communication settings.

I am taking this approach because my application needs to send user's personal info to my server and sending it over public WiFi does not sound right. Please let me know if there is better approach to it....

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered SSL?

Comment: Not all wifi is public, and you'll probably piss off many of your users by telling them they HAVE to use their data plan to use your software. Just use SSL like John Rudy said.

Comment: Not to mention that you automatically exclude iPod Touches when you do this, as they don't have a CDN. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response guys, definetely the application will use SSL for sending user's sensitive information to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one's writing a full answer ...

I don't know if it's possible to detect CDN vs Wi-Fi, although at some level it must be because the App Store is capable of determining such to prevent large CDN downloads. Of course, the App Store app has access to the private APIs; this functionality *may* not be exposed publicly. (I don't know if that is the case or not, but be sure you do not use private APIs for your app; the store won't accept it.)

That said, think about the use case of your app, and the marketplace. The iPhone OS and the iPhone App Store are more than just the phones themselves -- they're the iPhone *and* iPod Touch devices. iPod Touches do not have a CDN; they're Wi-Fi only for connectivity.

As Marc W said in a comment, not all Wi-Fi is public, not all public Wi-Fi is free, and you will likely upset a significant portion of your audience -- people (presumably and hopefully) giving you money.

A better solution would be to use SSL to provide encryption of the private data during transport. This is widely available, works over CDN or Wi-Fi, and provides all the security you should need.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Apple Reachability example code, you can test for how you would access a host - however I agree with the other posters that you should consider encrypting your data and let your user's determine how they want to connect to the Internet, and not force one form of connection.

-t